# What does an entire function whose images are normal matrices look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

I'd like to ask about the properties of a matrix-valued function $A:\mathbb C\to M_n(\mathbb C)$ where each entry of $A$ is an entire function and $A(z)$ is invertible and normal for every $z\in\mathbb C$.

I have difficultly to even come up with an interesting example of such a matrix-valued function. If $A$ is always Hermitian or always unitary, $A$ must be constant. Every non-constant example that I could find turned out to be uninteresting: it could be written in the form of
$$
A(z)=UD(z)U^\ast,\tag{1}
$$
where $U$ is some constant unitary matrix and $D(z)$ is some diagonal matrix function. This includes the cases where $A=f(z)M$ or $A=e^{f(z)K}$, in which $f$ is an entire scalar function, $M$ is a constant normal matrix and $K$ is a constant skew-Hermitian matrix.

Must $A$ be in the form of $(1)$? If not, is there any complete characterisation of $A$? Answers with the invertibility requirement removed are also welcomed.

Comment: Entire functions are at least a little  bit rigid; do you have any examples that you find interesting, where we let the elements share definition on, say, the unit disc?

Answer (score 1):

When $t\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow A(t)$ is real analytic and $A(t)$ is normal, then, LOCALLY, there are analytic parametrizations of the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of $A(t)$.

cf. https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/DC-perturb.pdf

I think that a similar result stands (but we have to show it!) for $z\in\mathbb{C}\rightarrow A(z)$ complex holomorphic and $A(z)$ complex normal (it's not the same situation as for the application $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow f(u,v)+ig(u,v)$, where $f,g$ are analytic real, because, here, there are relations between the derivatives of $f,g$).

If it's true, locally, one has $A(z)=U(z)D(z)U^*(z)$ where $U(z)$ is holomorphic unitary and $D(z)=diag(f_i(z))$ where $f_i$ is holomorphic; since the columns vectors of $U$ have a constant length, these vectors are constant on a connected open subset. Finally $A(z)=UD(z)U^*$ where $U$ is constant unitary.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't *"we have to show it"...* the hard part? ;-D The trouble with a complex holomorphic $A(z)$ is that it seems hard to make inferences about the eigenvectors. E.g. in the paper you linked to, property (O) suggests that the eigenvalues are at best Lipchitz. Nothing about the eigenvectors are mentioned. Even if the eigenvectors can be chosen to be Lipschitz locally, it seems a great leap to infer that $A(z)=UD(z)U^\ast$ from $A(z)=U(z)D(z)U^\ast(z)$.

Comment: It's better to look at (A) and (L). For $1$ real variable, an analytic parametrization exists; when there is more than one real variable, there is a finite analytic covering associated to the eigenvectors. Clearly, we have to show that we can avoid the second case for an holomorphic function. Anyway, the implicit function theorem exists for holomorphic functions. When $n=2$, it isn't difficult to see that the required solutions are in the form $f(z)I_2+g(z)N$ where $N$ is a fixed normal matrix.